# How To Get Data From 3rd Party App Like - Whatsdog Take From Whatsapp?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on an android app, and I wanted to make one like whatsdog, just for the knowledge.

Does anyone know what kind of API or SDK whatsdog uses to give a notification as soon as any of my contacts come online?

I searched a lot but got no answer so I thought I would ask here!

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatsdog may have taken permission from whatsapp officially for this purpose !

You can receive data via content provider . or if the third party app provide sdk or api , that will be another option .

Thanks

Comment: Any other Knowledge ?

Comment: I dont think whatsapp needs a third party ! If they want to provide this feature they can implement it there in Whatsapp itself .

Comment: so what you suggest ? there is no any sdk or api by whatsapp , and as I recall you cant access user status via content provider.@MeghalAgrawal